# setting vlc npapi plugin path

Tags: firefox, mozilla, vlc, npapi

I have customized the vlc npapi plugin. Right now I have to replace the "npvlc.dll" file in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC with my npvlc.dll

I want to know how can I change the path of this plugin. I tried changing the following registry file but this does not work. It just show a blank firefox or chrome window. I have tried setting path as folder name containing the dll or full path to dll or restarting the computer etc.

Note: When I do "about:plugins" in firefox, I can see the npapi plugin path changed to new location

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@videolan.org/vlc,version=2.0.5]
"Description"="VLC Multimedia Plugin"
"Path"=XXX
"Product"="VLC media player"
"Vendor"="VideoLAN"
"Version"="2.0.5"
```

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly; that's how you change the path.  Make sure there is only one entry, e.g. double check both HKCU and HKLM to make sure that there isn't an extra entry throwing you off.

Comment: Hi tax thanks for replying. I double checked there is no registry with same npapi mentioned in it.  Also I think the path is getting changed as when I set path the plugin is not loaded at all. Its not like it is being loaded from old location. So registry change is working. Its just not able to load it from new location. Also I have tried copying the other dll like libvlc.dll also to new location. But does not work. What do you think ?

Comment: Ok I just found the error. I had to copy the plugins folder to my directory as well. Now its working. Is there any way I dont have to do it?

Comment: Also do you know how can  I achieve the this in linux ?

Comment: there is no reason you'd need to copy the plugins folder unless for some reason the plugin itself requires it. AFAIK the only way to install things on linux is to symlink or copy it to the appropriate folder, though you can put it in the user's home dir somewhere I believe

Comment: I am able to do it on windows without copying anything. On linux I read I have to copy it but that removes the original plugin. I was trying to do something so that both plugins are there and only my page loads my plugin rest of application should load the default plugin